# Use induction to show that this improper integral exists

Tags: analysis

> Let $m,n \ge 0$ be positive integers. Using induction on $n$ or otherwise, show that the improper integral $$\int_0^1 x^m \left(\log x\right)^n dx$$ exists, and give a closed-form expression for it.

I'm a bit confused by the concept of induction on an integral, any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Induction is meant to be on $m$ and $n$. The fact that there is an integral in conceptually of no consequence, in that regard.

Comment: "exists" is a weird word here; i think it should be "converges"

Comment: Just use induction in $n$ for fixed $m$, and after you had done it use induction in $m$.

Comment: It would likely be better to write that $m,n > 0$ since they must be **positive** integers by hypothesis.

Comment: How is induction on an integral different from induction in some more algebraic example?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

For $m,n>0$ and $0 <x <1$

$$|x^m\ln^n (x)|\leq -\ln (x) $$
and
$\int_0^1\ln (x)dx $ converges thus by comparison, the integral $I_{m,n} $  is absolutely convergent.

to find a recursive formula, use by parts integration.
it will be of the form

$$I_{m,n}=\frac {n}{m+1}I_{m,n-1} $$